# Overwriting, saving, using stream. Are they really different?

Tags: c#, file-io, stream, overwrite

I want to make a file unusable. Does it really make sense if I overwrite it?

Is there a difference between overwriting, using stream, saving or just appending text?

<sup>Note: I want to delete the file afterwards and avoid recovery.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending probably won't help.  If you open the file for reading and writing, point to the beginning, and start writing, that probably has the best chance of working (from a high-level language like C#).

You may have to get even lower-level to really do this, otherwise you risk the OS using a different portion of the disk for your new data, defeating the purpose.  But I suspect the above should work.